Two pdf417 with same encoded data look totally different. Why is that so?
Im trying to recreate a barcode from driver license, which looks like this:

I recreated it with treepoem python application:

The encoded data is the same and generated barcode has the same number of columns and rows, but visually they are totally different. Why is that so? Is there any way to change how visually the generated pdf417 looks?
I tried to change the security level and application, but it was not helpful. I want generated barcode looks exactly same as on original.

They look the exact same to me, one is just a poor quality photo copy and the other is an actual digital representation of the same barcode. Definitely don't worry about not being able to make barcodes that look like the original.

Also, what happens when you scan them both? Is it the same data or different? Barcode generation randomness varies by barcode 'font'. Some are always the same for the same content, some are not.

Hey, I don't really see why this question should be voted to close. Being able to faithfully reproduce algorithms should be at the heart of this site. The problem here is that the codes really are different because of how they deal with error correction and row counting.

@ssice: "Hey, I don't really see .... voted to close"  Because the code, for "I recreated ... python application" is missing and stackoverflow is about programming, not about comparing barcodes... ?

@Luuk the code for recreating what he did with treepoem is trivially simple to write (treepoem.generate_barcode("pdf417", content, options={})); the issue here is on different inputs to the PDF417 algorithm itself. I believe algorithmic questions are on topic

I'm asking not because I have any knowledge of the OP, but because I approved it from Staging Ground thinking it was a fair question.

Your original barcode contains an error correction length of 64, while the one you generated uses 128.
Treepoem uses BWIPP and ghostscript as the backend and they can be customized up to an extent, but if you force the number of rows it will increase the security level.

Thank you so much! Any points how to change error correction length to 64, insted of 128? Looks like treepoem do not provide any option to change it.

The barcode was created with given parameters of error_correction:  5, columns quantity: 13 and rows quantity: 31. But how to customize error correction length?
